# How are serial ports set to 19200 baud in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, serial-port, baud-rate

I'm supposed to modify an application written in 16-bit assembly which uses serial port. One of the objectives is to support speed of 19200 baud. Most of the resources I've read (for example [this](http://arl.wustl.edu/~lockwood/class/cs306/books/artofasm/Chapter_13/CH13-3.html#HEADING3-1)) on the Internet show the way of doing it using INT 14h. I basically write a magic number into al register, call the interrupt and the port is (hopefully) set. The OS's system call application is using to set up the serial port is using the same method (I'm free to modify it if needed).

The problem with that approach is that the field which sets the speed is a 3-bit field and the maximum speed if 9600 baud. How do I use higher speeds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with BIOS functionality, but if you know more about the serial port's underlying [UART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver/transmitter) chip, you can very probably program it directly, bypassing the BIOS' support for it.

For instance, the classic [16550 UART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16550_UART) (a datasheet for which is found for instance [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pc16550d.pdf)) supports up to around 1 Mbps, and uses two 8-bit registers to express the desired clock scaling.

[Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/8250_UART_Programming#Divisor_Latch_Bytes) is a reference text on doing exactly that, i.e. programming the "divisor latch bytes" to set a desired baud rate. It's clear from the accompanying code that for a COM1 with a base I/O address of `0x3f8`, you will find the low-order divisor byte at `0x3f8` and the high-order byte at `0x3f9`.

Comment: Do you maybe know how to send data to the registers of the 16550? I guess that they may be mapped to some location in the memory but I'm having problems figuring out which ones.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: Use the `IN` and `OUT` instructions.

Comment: Back in the time there was almost no memory mapped IO. You need to use the `out` instruction, look at http://www.beyondlogic.org/serial/serial.htm#8